# Hyperlink is not working properly on hover

Tags: html, href

On hover, the hyperlink is working only on few places.
It is working fine on 'Food' tab when 'Gear' tab is active but not on 'Gear' when 'Food' tab is active. [Click](https://www.liveprepared.com/food) to check. Let me know if more details help.

Comment: The transparent part of the image above 'Gear' is covering the button. Next time try right clicking and selecting _inspect element_.

Comment: Given the (accepted) answer; what'll happen if and when that website should cease to exist or ends up being used for something else? There should have been relevant code posted here. The php tag alone doesn't support the question, yet alone any tags used since there is no source code supplied. The question is unclear for too many reasons.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I agree that php tag itself is not sufficient to explain how it is related to. I was suspecting some html code and asked others if they need more details to check the issue better.

Comment: @user3282626 Tags used must contain relevance and code in order to support it. Members helping look at and follow those tags; I for one being mostly "php". Others may be following that and "html" and "opencart" thinking it could be related to those; they're misleading. I'm not saying this in a bad voice btw *lol!* I'm just stating that in general. Also and as I stated earlier; should the website no longer exist, the question won't help anyone. Maybe the given answer but there won't be anything to verify against those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your photo of the gear box overlaps the link.

[image]

Comment: Side note: learn to love your browser's web inspector. This was trivially solvable just by right-clicking on the non-functional link and saying "inspect element" in Chrome.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks Ceejayoz. I was just checking the anchor tags in "inspect element". Yeah, I should check all over. Thanks again.

Comment: The question's getting more and more unclear (as per [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44505219/hyperlink-is-not-working-properly-on-hover#comment76004690_44505219) I left under the question) and who Kishor is; the OP (other account)? a collegue of?

Answer (score 2):

In the given website I can see that image above gear tab (32070_120Vault_1up_Angle_1500x_banner.png) is over lapping with the gear button. So when you hover on gear buttom its actually hovering on the image.

There are 2 solutions : 

  1. you can fix the image by editing it to the right size by trimming the unwanted space in bottom.

2. you can set higher value to `z-index` for "cat-tab" class. I can see then "side-top-image" class has z-index:9. So what you can do is, set the below CSS 

`.cat-tab {` 
      `position: relative;`
      `z-index: 10;`
`}`

I hope this should solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for css suggestion. It is working great but I had to replace the image with different size.